# I'm trying now to hook up my postgres database but am a little unfamiliar with where I should place my db information

Tags: django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django

as it is using a little different syntax than I am used to seeing. In my base.py settings file:

```
    DATABASES = {

'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL', default='postgres://project'),

}
```

Where do I place the typical database info like User, Host, Password, etc? In the section above in base.py or overide it in local.py settings file? As is, I've created the database in postgres using the same slug name in cookiecutter project setup but I'm getting a django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied.

PS: I'm using windows 10 and wonder if it could have something to do with the pg_hba.conf file? Something about setting a value to trust for local?

Comment: The [django documentation on the `DATABASES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases) includes an example configuration for postgresql. What exactly are you confused about here?

Comment: it happens that the syntax is a lil bit different when you set up a django project with cookiecutter since it comes with django-environ that modifies the database settings. When I try to run migrations or just the server it throws that error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied".

Comment: That explains the different syntax. Looking at [django-environ's README](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ/blob/develop/README.rst) configuration should be fairly straight forward. It's just expecting a postgresql connection URI in that environment variable.